# How to say to Windows to interpret a script in Python?

Tags: python, windows

I know, in linux like systems I can add this header to make my script interpreted with Python:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
```

Is there a way to do something similar in Windows? I want Windows to ignore file extension (if it's possible) and to see at the header of the script.

Comment: CMD and PowerShell try `CreateProcess` first. This function doesn't use shebangs. If the file extension is .BAT or .CMD, it rewrites the command line to use the default batch handler, `%ComSpec% /c`. Otherwise it tries to execute the found file as a PE executable. If `CreateProcess` fails, the shell tries `ShellExecuteEx`, which uses the file extension to get an associated template command from the registry to build a command line for `CreateProcess`.

Comment: On Linux, extensions are meaningless. But not on windows. Ignoring them wouldn't be easy.

Comment: @frederick99, the way Python currently handles this is to embed the script in an executable that runs python.exe, linked by a Job object. It uses the .EXE extension, but you can use any extension to run the file in PowerShell or CMD. PowerShell requires the extension to be in `PATHEXT`, and CMD requires this just for files without an extension (i.e. the extension is "."). Explorer doesn't try `CreateProcess` first, so in that case you'll need to add a new "exec" (default friendly name "Execute") right-click command to "HKLM\Software\Classes\*\shell" that runs the template `"%1" %*`.